Azure connection issues locally
Unable to connect to azure from my laptop unless I hotspot first.
I tried az login which just hangs on 'Starting new HTTPS connection login.microsoftonline.com:443' seen a suggestion online to try python -c "import requests; print(requests.get('http://login.microsoftonline.com/').status_code)" and get a 200.
Mysteriously I connect my laptop to my phones hotspot and I'm able to connect, and when I switch back to ISPs router connections that worked on my hotspot still work but those I didn't test on my hotspot still don't work.
Still unable to az login. I could blame my router but if it's successfully working for resources that I assume were 'reset' during hotspotting then I feel its more my setup needs a big reboot to start from scratch. Any suggestions appreciated.
EDIT: extra information, so I have 4 database server connections on SQL Server, lets give them names: dev, sandbox, prod1, prod2.
Before hotspot I couldn't connect to any. I hotspotted and connected to dev and prod1. Switched back to router and can still connect to dev and prod1 but not sandbox or prod2 despite they are on the same subscription just different resources. I assume when connections are established a 'happy' token to stored to allow connections and the only thing I can assume is my router is blocking this for 'new' connections. Bear in mind I'm hotspotting to my phone which is actually connected to the same router both wirelessly. Losing my mind.

Have you tried clearing DNS cache? @jamessouthall

Disabled IPv6 on my router and everything now works as expected.
